# How to make blinking two images and don't see the flash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a problem and I don't know if it's possible to find a solution..

So, I have two complementary images with "checkerboard" that I would like to make flashing simultaneous. These images have the same size and are superimposed.

The aim is to flash these images and don't see the flash...

It seems to me that if I have between 25 and 30 images per seconds, I will not see jerk.
So one image every each ( 1s/30image = ) 0,033 seconds.

The minimum value of NSTimeInterval is

```
NSTimeInterval ti = 0.000000001;
```

but I don't know if NSTimer accept a minimum value.

---

I have tried two principal solutions with this **`NSTimer`** :

```
NSTimeInterval ti = 0.033; // I have tried less than this value

NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 1.0];
NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                                      interval: ti
                                        target: self
                                      selector:@selector(flash:)
                                      userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

The target method with **`alpha`**

```
-(void)flash:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(boolean == 0){
        _image2.alpha = 0;
        boolean = 1;
    }else{
        _image2.alpha = 1;
        boolean = 0;
    }
}
```

Or with the **`bringSubviewToFront`** (similar z-index in HTML)

```
-(void)flash:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(boolean == 0){
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_image2];
        boolean = 1;
    }else{
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_image1];
        boolean = 0;
    }
}
```

But nothing works good. I have tried on my Mac and on my iPhone 5S. Maybe that the frequency of displaying changes the result... If someone can help me, It would be great.

Comment: Try start with ti = 1.0 and work your way down.

Comment: If it's two images, you may want to use the property `animationImages` of `UIImageView`...

Comment: @BooRanger I have already tried this but it doesn't work even if I see changes. I didn't know this method. I'm going to try :). Thanks

Comment: Can you explain this further -- "flash these images and don't see the flash"? Do you just want to see one image change to the other, or one fade to the other, something else? 0.033 seconds seems awful fast, do you really want it that fast, or are you doing that to get rid of the "flash"?

Comment: @rdelmar One images has holes that the other image doesn't have, so I want to display consecutively these images quickly to don't see the transition effect. That is why the interval is very small. The user will not see the différence on the screen because the frequency will be too fast than the perception of the human eye. I hope that I am understandable.

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand -- if you don't want the user to see the switch, why not just composite the two images into one image?

Comment: It's a project and I need to create this function :/

Comment: Well, that seems like a strange project. But anyway, have you tried a CADisplayLink instead of a timer? It's synced to the display refresh rate (1/60 of a second) which might give you a better effect.

Comment: CADisplayLink it's maybe a good solution. I will try this class. Thanks :)